# Azure AD Authentication Experience Flow

Tags: azure-active-directory

Need some guidance on whether the UI flow for Azure AD can be customized, such that we can do some level of Authorization based on the UPN & Tenantid, before Authentication.

In the current state of my App, when it is initiated for the first time, the Authentication happens and then the Consent. As the Authentication flow finishes, the app checks if the Tenant is eligible for access rights (authorized) and then the app continues.

Current FLOW : Authentication > User Consent

Requested FLOW: Check Tenant ID > Validate Access > Authentication > User Consent

Need the ability to control this flow such that we can validate the user’s email address prior to authentication to make sure the user has access to the app. Basically not doing an Authentication if the UPN is not authorized. The goal is when the app is available on the App Store, while it can be downloaded by anyone, would like to control the experience of the login.

For Auth we are using MSAL. Also we have a version of the app that uses OpenID Connect.

Appreciate guidance.

Comment: I am going to say this is generally not possible, but before I make it an answer to the question, I want to propose the following question: If the user is not signed in, how would you "check Tenant ID"? How would you know what their tenant id **would** be?

Comment: One thing you could do is use a tenant specific sign in endpoint, but this only works for a single tenant application, not for multiple tenants... unless you created different sign in buttons for each tenant. With a tenant specific sign in endpoint, users from other tenants will be blocked from signing in, as the login screen would say "user not found" for users outside the tenant.

Comment: Thanks Shawn - The idea that was floated is as follows...
a. Build  a list of TenantIds that will have access to the App
b. Present user with a form to specify the UPN
c. Based on UPN determine the TenantID and validate against the list
d. If retrieved TenantID is in the list of allowed Tenants, proceed to Authentication
This will only happen at the time of first time launch of the app.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description , your requirement is to restrict certain tenants when using multi-tenant applications on Azure AD . AFAIK ,Azure AD currently doesn't have an application configuration property that maps to a tenant allow list for a multi-tenant app.

The workaround would be performing that validation in your own code in application by checking the tenantID (tid) claim in JWT token . Controlling access will need to happen as part of authorizing the user in your app , not before authentication in your scenario .